# How to style <?php html5blank_nav(); ?> in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, html

I've used a HTML 5 Blank template and converted it to a WordPress theme successfully.

But when I use this code: `<?php html5blank_nav(); ?>` to auto populate the main navigation it of course looses the template styling.

I've enqueued all the css but from what I understand I need to use the below code to tell the menu how to be styled:

**PHP:**

```
function html5blank_nav()
{
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
        )
    );
}
```

If you take a look at http://geekcloud.co.uk - this is the header navigation menu style im trying to achieve using this code: .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: missing above code: <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add style to <?php html5blank\_nav(); ?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769545/how-to-add-style-to-php-html5blank-nav)

Comment: Check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/ as it teaches you how `wp_nav_menu` works. You do not require `wp_nav_menu` to be inside another function i.e. `html5blank_nav`. It'll work perfectly fine when used on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) page on the Wordpress developer documentation.

You have to register the stylesheet in your functions.php file with
    `wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );`

Good luck developing!

Comment: Thanks for the update DeathCamel57.

Have you done this before?

Trying to recreate the header navigation like this: http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/5.7.2/demo-construction.html

Comment: I have done it before. Make your CSS file for the navbar, then enqueue it.

Comment: look at [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you for the help. All the css and scripts are enqueued in functions.php. But I'm still not able to style the <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>.
Does this below code make sense:

Comment: function html5blank_nav()
{
 wp_nav_menu(
 array(
  'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
  'menu'            => '',
  'container'       => 'div',
  'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
  'container_id'    => '',
  'menu_class'      => 'menu',
  'menu_id'         => '',
  'echo'            => true,
  'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
  'before'          => '',
  'after'           => '',
  'link_before'     => '',
  'link_after'      => '',
  'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
  'depth'           => 0,
  'walker'          => ''
  )
 );
}

Comment: It would appear I need to use this code to style the menu?

Comment: That code goes in the `functions.php` file. It contains what the classes, id's, and elements contain. You CSS file would need to style those elements properly.

Comment: If you're not familiar with starting theme development from scratch, look at this [boilerplate theme](https://github.com/tonik/theme)

Comment: I wonder if you could do this for me? I could pay you of course.

Comment: Yes, check out http://geekcloud.co.uk
The header navigation is the first issue. Its just static HTML code which I can make dynamic with the above code but I cant style it :(
Also how does the header menu or sidebar menu know when to be active?
I need to work out a way for menu items to stay focused when on that page if that makes sense?
Any help would be amazing!

Comment: I'll make an example, and push it to github most likely within the next 24 hours. I'll link you when the header is done.

Comment: To be honest, I had forgotten about it. However, I happened to work on something on Github that required me to do it. Here's a link to the commit that added support for dropdown menues. [Link](https://github.com/DeathCamel57/SAASC-WP-theme/commit/03d420f7b45dde2ee3a3d139177db46fc3d24103?diff=unified)